# Need help hovering over a dropdown list and selecting a specific dropdown option (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver, dropdown

This is my first post so bear with me. I'm trying to go into a dropdown list (Products) that is located in a toolbar at the top of the webpage. Once hovering over the dropdown Products, I'd like to click the one that is named ModMaster so I can navigate to the link 'https://www.modmaster.com'. How do I go about doing this?

I've tried several different methods but the core issue is that's unable to locate the element. If I explicitly wait for it to be visible, it times out.

I've tried using Select, javascript execute, simple find_by_element.click to no avail.

Really the end result just needs to be the current webpage needs to change into www.modmaster.com and keep me logged in. I appreciate any help!

Here is the HTML:

```
`<ul class="topbar-module-wrap"><li class="topbar-module"><div class="login-info dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Welcome, hidden</span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><label>User name:</label> hidden</li><li><label>Agency:</label> hidden</li><li class="divider"></li><li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li></ul></div></li><li class="topbar-module"><div id="product-dropdown" class="product-menu dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-menu-white-small"></i><span>Products</span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="https://amc.zywave.com/" target=""><div class="topbar-product-name">Account Management Center</div><div class="topbar-product-subtext"></div></a></li><li><a href="https://www.brokerbriefcase.com/" target="_blank"><div class="topbar-product-name">Broker Briefcase®</div><div class="topbar-product-subtext">Sales and Marketing Platform</div></a></li><li><a href="https://www.modmaster.com/" target="_blank"><div class="topbar-product-name">ModMaster®</div><div class="topbar-product-subtext">Mod Analysis Tool
```

Comment: please provide the code you have tried, and a little more context on the HTML since the page has a login. [mcve]